# Spark (2.3+) Java functions callable from PySpark/Python

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark

re Spark Doc 2.3:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.registerJavaFunction

> registerJavaFunction(name, javaClassName, returnType=None)[source]
>
> Register a Java user-defined function as a SQL function.
>
> In addition to a name and the function itself, the return type can be >optionally specified. When the return type is not specified we would infer it via reflection.
>
> Parameters:
>
> name – name of the user-defined function
>
> javaClassName – fully qualified name of java class
>
> returnType – the return type of the registered Java function. The value can be either a pyspark.sql.types.DataType object or a DDL-formatted type string.

---

My question:

I want to have a library of large number of UDFs, for Spark 2.3+, all written in Java and all accessible from PySpark/Python.

Reading documentation which I linked above it appears that the there is a **one to one mapping between a class and Java UDF function** (callable from Spark-SQL in PySpark).
So that if I have say 10 Java UDF functions then I need to create 10 public Java classes with 1 UDF per class to make them callable from PySpark/SQL.

Is this correct?

Can I create 1 public Java class and place a number of different UDFs inside the 1 class and make all UDFs callable from PySpark in Spark 2.3 ?

This post does **not** provide any **Java** sample code to help with my question. It looks like it is all in Scala. I want it all in Java please.
Do I need to extend a class or implement interface to do it in Java?
**Any links to sample Java code to be called from PySpark-SQL would be appreciated.**

[Spark: How to map Python with Scala or Java User Defined Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233737/spark-how-to-map-python-with-scala-or-java-user-defined-functions)

Comment: it is not a duplicate at all, I was asking re Java, all the code in the linked reply is in Scala.

Answer (score 2):

> So that if I have say 10 Java UDF functions then I need to create 10 public Java classes with 1 UDF per class to make them callable from PySpark/SQL.
>
> Is this correct?

Yes, that's correct. However you can:

- Use `UserDefinedFunction` and interface it as shown in [Spark: How to map Python with Scala or Java User Defined Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233737/spark-how-to-map-python-with-scala-or-java-user-defined-functions)
- Use `UDFRegistration.register` to register named `udfs`, and then just call [`org.apache.spark.sql.functions.callUDF`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@callUDF(udfName:String,cols:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) through Py4j for each registered function.

Comment: I have read the post you linked to before I posted my question. There is no mention of your suggestions there. Please be more specific. Perhaps you can provide a small example in Java? I was very specific in my question that I want it all done in Java, *not* Scala.

Answer (score 1):

Below very simple Java/Python/Pyspark code sample may help someone, I got it working on Spark 2.3.1 and Java 1.8 for a Java UDF callable from Python.

Note that this approach seems **very cumbersome** to me as you need a separate Java class for each one Java UDF. So for 50 discrete Java UDFs = 50 separate public Java classes! 
Ideally if a single public Java class could contain a number of individual Java UDFs, all packaged in a single JAR file this would be ideal. 
Alas I still dont know how to do it.

Improvement suggestions welcome!
Thank you

```
// Java 8 code 
package com.yourdomain.sparkUDF;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF0;
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;


public final class JavaUDFExample 
        implements UDF0<String> {
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}
// end of Java code
// make a jar file from above including all referenced jar Spark libraries

# PySPark Python code below
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark     import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Java UDF Example").getOrCreate() 

df = spark.read.json(r"c:\temp\temperatures.json")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("citytemps")

spark.udf.registerJavaFunction("getGuid", "com.yourdomain.sparkUDF.JavaUDFExample", StringType())

spark.sql("SELECT getguid() as guid, * FROM citytemps").show()
# end of PySpark-SQL Python code

DOS shell script to run on local Spark:

spark-submit --jars c:\dir\sparkjavaudf.jar python-udf-example.py
```